# Help with JavaME Function

Tags: java, java-me, operators, midp, integer-division

Could anyone explain to me how this MIDP Java function works? I'm particularly curious about the operators being used.

```
public static final int smoothDivide(int numerator, int denominator) {
    return (int) ((numerator << 16) / denominator + 32768L) >> 16;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: And this is what code-comments are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a division algorithm that rounds to the closest integer. It is equivalent to

```
Math.round((float) numerator / denominator)
```

for a large range of the integers, but cleaverly implemented without floating point operations.

The operators `<<` and `>>` are [bitwise shift left and shift right](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) operators.

---

#### Here is the intuition for how it works

First note that `<< 16` and `>> 16` are equivalent to `* 65536` and `/ 65536` respectively. So what the algorithm computes is the folowing:

```
            / numerator * 65536           \
result  =  ( ------------------  +  32768  )  /  65536
            \   denominator               /
```

That is, it scales up the numerator, divides it, adds half of the scale, and then scales it down again.

It is similar to the expression `(int) ((numerator + 0.5) / denominator)` which is a more common way to do "rounded" division (but it relies on floating point arithmetic).